# Unable to create a ec2 ubuntu instance node using chef and knife

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-ec2, chef-infra

I am new to knife and chef configuration management system, I was trying to create a ec2 ubuntu instance node using knife command line too.

I am able to run knife node list and knife node show node_name. But when ever I run the following command I get an error message also it says use -i instead of -I.

```
knife ec2 server create -I ami-10206d42 -S ~/key.pem -i ~/key.pem  --region ap-southeast-1  --flavor t1.micro --ssh-user ubuntu --groups default
```

This is the error message

```
Fog::Compute::AWS::NotFound: The key pair '~/key.pem' does not exist
```

Thought the key is present in the home folder.

Kindly help me

Comment: Replace `~` with real path (or $HOME). I guess the tilde is not expanded properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As has been mentioned, tilde expansion will not work in a Ruby environment without specific code as that's a [feature of the shell](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_03_04.html). You will want an absolute path to handle that.

So try changing `~` into `$HOME`.

Btw. Ruby can handle such expansion through [File.expand_path](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/File.html#method-c-expand_path).